# Can a material made of a heavier isotope of an element become harder or stronger?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, nuclear-physics, material-science, isotopes

I was wondering if any experiments have been done to measure if there is a change in the hardness or strength of a material made solely of a heavier isotope of an element which is a constituent of the material. Or if the strength or hardness increases with the increase in proportion of heavier isotopes of the atoms of a particular element jn the material.

Comment: Will 'Brinnel Hardness Test" be good for your question? And are you looking at any particular element Carbon, Tin....or in general.

Comment: It is known that isotopically pure C-12 diamond has a 50% greater thermal conductivity than regular diamond. However, that is phonon scattering at work. I cannot find any hardness measurements, but haven't looked too hard (pun intended).

Comment: I would think that adding a neutron to the nucleus would not affect the hardness.

Comment: I was wondering if this might be true for any material at all. I believe its true that neutrons have an affinity for protons and must be what holds them together. I'm speculating that neutrons have a little attractive forces left over which might slightly pull adjacent atoms to them making the material slightly more dense which might mean harder. My real question is if there are some attractive forces from neutrons left over from the nucleus they reside in.

Comment: Isotopically pure diamonds composed of only $C^{12}$ have been tested and found to be even harder than normal diamonds.  This could be because the $C^{13}$ atoms in normal diamonds act like impurities for some lattice properties (which could well lower the hardness).  I would bet that the same would be found if isotopically pure $C^{13}$ diamonds could be tested.

Answer (score 2):

The nuclear force is a contact force, with potential energy curve
$$
V \propto \frac{e^{-r/r_0}}{r}.
$$
The range parameter $r_0$ is roughly one femtometer.  Nuclei in a solid are typically $10^5\rm\,fm$ apart, so the nuclear interaction between nuclei from different atoms is astoundingly suppressed.

If you think of a solid as a lattice of atoms connected by springs with Hooke constant $k$, the natural frequencies of these oscillators, 
$$ \omega_0 = \sqrt{k/m}, $$ will be different for crystals of different isotopes.  For instance the mass difference between carbon-12 and carbon-13 is about 8%, so compared to a C-12 diamond a C-13 diamond would have about 4% smaller resonant frequency.  My naive expectation is that this would probably change heat capacity, and possibly change thermal conductivity, but I don't know very much about hardness or other mechanical properties.

Answer (score 2):

There is one small effect that has not yet been covered in the other answers.  When we solve Schrodinger's equation for the electron orbitals we use the so called reduced mass $$\mu=m_e m_n/(m_e+m_n)$$ so the solutions for the orbitals will be slightly different for the case where extra neutrons are added to the nucleus. The electron mass is so much smaller than the nuclear mass that this is a really minuscule effect and likely will not be experimentally observable for the properties that you are considering.

Comment: Your last sentence could maybe use a bit more clarification; I think you mean that the gravitational effect is very much weaker than electrostatic attraction (and therefore changing the nuclear mass by a modest amount has only a miniscule overall effect), but that has little to do with the electron's mass.

Comment: @NathanTuggy  No, I'm not referring to a gravitational effect, but to the effect on the electron wave function from s slightly different reduced mass.

Answer (score 0):

Drawing on my chemistry background and asking a few of my Ceramic Engineering friends, the answer is "No".  We had the consensus that the nucleus does not impart any physical property on the hardness or strength but the "electron cloud" and its interactions. The electrons are not affected in any way by the different in isotopes.